# Path connectedness is a topological invariant?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> $\textbf{PROBLEM}$
>
> Path-connectedness is a topological invariant

MY try: we can show that the image of a path connected space $X$ under a continuous mapping is path connected

Suppose $X$ is path connected space. let $\gamma : X \to Y$ be continuous bijective map. Take $x,y \in Y$, then can find $x',y' \in X$ such that $\gamma(x') = x$ and $\gamma(y')=y$. We know $X$ is path connected. Therefore, we can find a path $f$ from $x'$ to $y'$. in other words, such that $f(a) = x'$ and $f(b) = y'$. But then notice $\gamma f (a) = x$ and $\gamma f (b) =  y$. Therefore, $\gamma f$ is a path from $x$ to $y$. In particular, $Y$ is path connected.

MY question is: I feel like I haven't used the fact the $\gamma$ is injective. Is it necessary? Is this a correct approach to the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined paths to be injective mappings? In that case note that your composite map is injective since both $\gamma$ and $f$ are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’d replace $a$ and $b$ by $0$ and $1$: you can always take the domain of your path to be $[0,1]$.

The argument is fine: you’ve proved that path-connectedness, like connectedness, is preserved by continuous surjections. Of course any homeomorphism between spaces is a continuous surjection, so path-connectedness is a topological invariant.

You would need $\gamma$ to be injective if you were trying to prove that arcwise connectedness is a topological invariant: in that case the path must actually be an embedding of $[0,1]$ into the space, so $\gamma\circ f$ has to be injective.

Comment: thank you very much Brian for your feedback! I get it now. I have an unrelated question if you dont mind me asking: What does it mean for a function to have "compact support" ?

Comment: @Don: It means that $\operatorname{cl}\{x:f(x)\ne 0\}$ is compact.

Comment: @Don: You’re welcome.