# Is simply connectedness is a topological property?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

A topological space $X$ is called [simply-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) if it is path-connected and any continuous map 
$f:S^{1} \to X$
(where $S^1$ denotes the unit circle in Euclidean 2-space) can be contracted to a point in the following sense: there exists a continuous map $F:D^2 \to X$ (where  $D^2$ denotes the unit disk in Euclidean 2-space) such that F restricted to $S^{1}$ is $f.$

> **My Question**: Is Simply connectedness is a topological property? In other words, $f:X\to Y $ is a homeomorphism and if $X$ is simply connected space, can we say $Y$ is also a simply connected space?

Comment: Yes. You can compose homotopies with continuous maps.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, being simply-connected is preserved under homeomorphisms. Suppose $f : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism and $X$ is simply connected.

- First, [path-connectedness is a topological invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554193/path-connectedness-is-a-topological-invariant?rq=1), so $Y$ is path-connected too.
- Now, let $\gamma : S^1 \to Y$ be any (continuous) loop. Then $f^{-1} \circ \gamma : S^1 \to X$ is a continuous loop, and $X$ is simply-connected, so there exists $F : D^2 \to X$ such that $F_{\mid S^1} = f^{-1} \circ \gamma$. But then $G = f \circ F : D^2 \to X$ is also a continuous map, and $G_{\mid S^1} = f \circ f^{-1} \circ \gamma = \gamma$. Thus $\gamma$ can be contracted to a point.