# Are the topological spaces $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ and $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Two topological spaces are homeomorphic if there is a bijective continuous map between them that the inverse of this map is continuous too. I think the spaces $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ and $(0,1)\times (0,1)$(as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$) are not homeomorphic. But how we can prove that.

The properties of compactness or connectivity cannot help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** If you remove $(0,0)$ from the first space, it is still simply connected

Comment: @Darman: ....because [simply connectedness is s topological property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369962/is-simply-connectedness-is-a-topological-property)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: when you remove any point of $(0,1)^2$, you get a space homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{0\}$, thus homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^{+*}$.

When you remove $(0,0)$ from $[0,1)^2$, you get a space homeomorphic to $\{x,y \geq 0,\,x+y >0\}$, which is (polar coordinates) homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{+*} \times [0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Now how do you show $\mathbb{R}^{+*} \times [0,\pi/2]$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^{+*}$?

Comment: I was trying to think of something else, but it all boils down to homotopy anyway, I would guess.

Answer (score 0):

In $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ you have boundary points which belong to the set.

On the other hand there is no boundary points of $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ which belong to it.

Comment: @Darman I guess he is referring to [Manifold boundary](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=30&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiRzqu20qLiAhU2xIsBHRcSDx0QwaICMB16BAgLEBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.encyclopediaofmath.org%2Findex.php%2FBoundary_(of_a_manifold)&usg=AOvVaw38Vz_SAqsOeKdD8vM77X0V)

Comment: There's still a lot  of work to do to  show this implies the sets are not homeomorphic. All that's obvious from  this is that there is no self-homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^2$ that takes one set to the other...

Comment: The  problem  is that "$p$  is a boundary point of $A$" does not depend  just on the topology of$A$; "boundary point" applies to subsets of topological spaces, not to topological spaces _per se_.