# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2-B(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Are $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2-B(0,1)$ homeomorphic? I'm trying to find a homeomorphism between the half of a hyperboloid of one sheet, $$C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2-z^2=1,\textrm{ }z\geq 0\},$$ and the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. I've already showed that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2-B(0,1)$ by defining the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2-B(0,1)\to C$, $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1})$.

Comment: Is $B(0,1)$ the unit disk? If so, they can't be homeomorphic as $\Bbb{R}^2$ is simply connected but not $\mathbb{R}^2 - B(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, $B(0,1)$ is the unit disk. I see. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Side comment: $C$ isn't a cone. (It's half of a hyperboloid of one sheet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer, since $\Bbb{R}^2$ is simply connected but  $\Bbb{R}^2 - B(0,1)$ is not, and [homeomorphism preserves simply connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369962/is-simply-connectedness-is-a-topological-property), they are not homeomorphic.